# Unable to ProxyPass foldername with spaces

Tags: apache

**Working**

```
ProxyPassMatch /_vti_bin/(.*) http://www.somedomain.com/_vti_bin/$1

ProxyPass /_vti_bin http://www.somedomain.com/_vti_bin/  retry=0 timeout=60
```

**Not working**

```
ProxyPassMatch /Style%20Library/(.*) http://www.somedomain.com/Style%20Library/$1

ProxyPass /Style%20Library/ http://www.somedomain.com/Style%20Library retry=0 timeout=60
```

**In simple**

I am able to refer a  folder name : 'app'

But,unable to refer to a folder name : 'app spot'

Comment: Try adding nocanon to ProxyPass

Comment: Tried like the below it didnt work.

ProxyPassMatch /Style%20Library/(.*) 
http://www.somedomain.com/Style%20Library/$1 nocanon 

ProxyPass /Style%20Library/ http://www.somedomain.com/Style%20Library retry=0 timeout=60 nocanon

Comment: Do you have a RewriteRule , in which case the white spaces can get encoded twice to become %2520 , hook up Fiddler and check how the URL looks like.

Comment: hook up Fiddler and check how the URL looks like ?

Comment: Get Fiddler to intercept HTTP traffic : http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: I checked it in the server logs and could see it is going with spaces as %20%

Comment: It can't be  %20% either  %20 or %2520. Also you don't have to use both ProxyPassMatch and ProxyPass as both provide same functionality and former supports RegEx. Now with ProxyPassMatch you might want to re-check your regEx to grt rid of %20: ProxyPassMatch /Style Library/(.*)